# Why run same function with same input twice waste different time on python?

Tags: python, performance, math, floating-point

The python code below tries to run the same function twice and outputs the runtime :

```
def test_f(f1,ip):
    st = time.time()
    f1(*ip)
    print(time.time()-st)

test_f(math.sin,[100])
test_f(math.sin,[100])
```

The outputs of three tests are below:

```
7.15255737305e-06
1.19209289551e-06

7.86781311035e-06
9.53674316406e-07

6.91413879395e-06
9.53674316406e-07
```

I do not know why the outputs are so different ? Why the second execution is faster than the first ? I also try to run five times, and the results are below :

```
8.10623168945e-06
1.19209289551e-06
0.0
0.0
0.0
```

Comment: `time` compared to other timing methods is not very accurate. Try running our test using `timeit.timeit` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CPython, When a module is compiled, a code object is created (which contains the byte code), but an actual function invocation requires a frame object (which involves some run-time allocation and initialization). As an optimization, these frame objects are sometimes kept alive as "zombies" for later reuse. Here is part of an extensive comment in the source for [frameobject.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/frameobject.c):

> /* Stack frames are allocated and deallocated at a considerable rate. 
>       In an attempt to improve the speed of function calls, we:
>
> ```
> 1. Hold a single "zombie" frame on each code object. This retains 
> the allocated and initialised frame object from an invocation of 
> the code object. The zombie is reanimated the next time we need a 
> frame object for that code object. Doing this saves the malloc/ 
> realloc required when using a free_list frame that isn't the 
> correct size. It also saves some field initialisation.
> ```

If what you are observing isn't a simple artifact of the unreliability of `time.time` at that resolution, it is the time difference between creating a zombie (slower) and reanimating a zombie (quicker).